# Angular Material Snackbar global configuration

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

I'm following the guide on Angular Material github to set custom global configuration to use on the snackbar module. This is the [guide I'm following](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/snack-bar/snack-bar.md#setting-the-global-configuration-defaults).

However, as sais in the docs, there is no export for `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` only `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA` but it's not overriding the default configuration.

This is what I tried:

```
import { MatSnackBarModule, MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

providers: [
    { provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: { duration: 2500 } }
]
```

I also tried like this:

```
{ provide: MatSnackBarConfig, useValue: { duration: 2500 } }
{ provide: MatSnackBarConfig, useClass: SnackClass }
```

But none of the options is working. The snack never auto dismiss after the specified time.

Comment: What version of Angular Material are you using?

Comment: @Edric version 5.2.5

Comment: `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` was implemented since `6.0.0-beta.4`

Answer (score 6):

```
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

providers: [
  {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 2500}}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are messing up stuffs here

You should change duration here:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {duration: 2500}}
  ]
})
```

and you must inject MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA inside your constructor:

```
import {MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA} from '@angular/material';

constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

Comment: But there is no export for `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS`. Where do I need to import it from?

Comment: You only need to import this:

import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

see the documentation here: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api

Comment: It's not a must for importing `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA` to the snackbar unless it's a custom snackbar component and whether you want to supply any data to the custom snackbar component.