# MatSnackBar default action label

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, snackbar, angular13

In order to not always specify the same options when opening a snackbar, I am looking into possible ways to provide default values. For the `duration` I already found a way to specify a default value via `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022568/11425760).

Is there a way to achieve something similar for the button label, so I do not always have to specify it again when opening a snackbar? To clarify, I am talking about the second argument where I pass `OK` in this example:

```
this.snackBar.open('Text', 'OK');
```

Comment: You should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950143/how-to-put-the-action-button-when-using-the-snackbar-openfromcomponent-metho